# iproute2 ss - exclude sockets bound to loopback addresses

Tags: ss

often I take a look at listening sockets with `ss -nlptu`, this list often includes few/dozen socket bound on either an ipv4 or ipv6 loopback address. As we know there are a few valid ipv4 loopback addresses to bind to, so I would rather not use something like grep to exclude the most common ones if I can avoid it.

Is there a way to have `ss` exclude local/loopback listening ports from its listing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ss` has a built-in filter language, alas it's almost undocumented in the man page. The last remnents of this documentation are in *iproute2* version v4.13.0 and were removed with this commit:

> [doc: remove outdated ss documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/?id=d77ce080d33370d90de8b123cd143e9599dc1ca6)
> The current version is
> well documented on man page. The latex documentation is very old and
> was never upated.

The file `ss.sgml` might appear in other formats once compiled/distributed.

Here's an example:

> ```
> <item>A. Address/port match, where address is checked against mask
>       and port is either wildcard or exact. It is one of:
>  
> <tscreen><verb>
>         dst prefix:port
>         src prefix:port
>         src unix:STRING
>         src link:protocol:ifindex
>         src nl:channel:pid
> </verb></tscreen>
>
>       Both prefix and port may be absent or replaced with <tt/*/,
>       which means wildcard. UNIX socket use more powerful scheme
>       matching to socket names by shell wildcards. Also, prefixes
>       unix: and link: may be omitted, if address family is evident
>       from context (with option <tt/-x/ or with <tt/-f unix/
>       or with <tt/unix/ keyword) 
>
> <p>
> ```

So if you want to exclude any loopback addresses, you can do:

```
ss -nlptu '! src 127.0.0.0/8 and ! src [::1]'
```

Quotes are actually required only because of the IPv6 address format, but then once using quotes, better quote everything.

Comment: super interesting, thanks for pointing that out; I'm looking at version 4.18.0-1ubuntu2~ubuntu18.04.1 and I notice that `misc/ssfilter.y` gives me a "bison bellows" error message for the expression you've shown. I think this version doesn't understand multiple exclamation points, having a `! expr and ! expr` gives this error for me, were `! expr and expr` works (but uselessly filtered out everything)

Comment: I just created an ubuntu bionic container, and the same command works correctly without triggering any warning. Same if running the command with iproute2 v4.9 or iproute v5.8 too. So I'm surprised by your own result. The only difference is I'm running a kernel 5.8. Oh Ubuntu 18's stock iproute2 is version 4.15 rather than 4.18. Maybe the 4.18 version only has an issue?

Comment: As a work-around syntax, can you try this instead? `ss -nlptu 'not ( src 127.0.0.0/8 or src [::1] )'`  Please mind the single quotes and spaces.

Comment: I had tried that and no, same error; though I', unsure why, it works without the not prefix, and it also doesn't work with separated not subexpressions like `(not expr) and (not expr)`. this is probably just an obsolete version thing, i'm guessing latest iproute2 does work

Comment: Thr trouble is I can't reproduce any error. Can you try *any* other version of iproute2? Even the stock 4.15 from stock ubuntu 18

Comment: I tried the version of iproute2 from debian sid source (at time of writing 5.9.0-1) and that version did accept your recommended filter(s) just fine :) thank you much for your expertise, I plan to assign a bounty because I think this info is so important